# Visual studio designer wont display my user controls but runs the application fine

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

for some reason my user controls display the error 'Cannot locate resource 'resources/backicon.png'. I am confused as to why this is happening as the program runs fine it just cannot create an instance of the controls in the designer and is displaying a blue warning here: ''. The path in the error is 'resources/backicon.png' however in the actual user control the path is specified as '/Resources/BackIcon.png'. Also the build action for the images is set to resource.

(I'm running Visual studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop)

Comment: Right click on your project -> Build -> Change **Platform Target** to x86. Does this help?

Comment: Have you tried a clean/rebuild? Do you call it from inside a folder? Have you tried ../Resources/BackIcon.png?

Comment: Thanks @Moddam the problem was that i had the user controls inside a folder so you were right i should have used the path ../Resources/BackIcon.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specify the assembly name in the path although it belongs to the same assembly.

```
pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/MyResourcesFolder/MyImage.png
```

Make sure You set the build action of the image to the type 'Resource'.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click->Clean
Once its cleaned 
Now RightClick-> Rebuild
You will see the blue warning gone.
Its because your user control must be added later on which resulted in designer not having any reference as its using previous build as base

Comment: Rebuilding actually cleans and builds in in one, no need to clean first.

Comment: Still sometimes I found the blue warning not going away while doing simple rebuilding hence have resorted to clean and rebuild to be on safe side :P

Comment: Cleaning the solution does make the controls re appear but with a yellow warning sign with a exclamation mark in the top left of the control. Then when i rebuild the solution the problem is the same as before.